# ESP32 + TLC5940

Tags: arduino, esp32

i want to use some TLC5940 ICs with the ESP32 but i can't find a library that supports the combination.
I used [this library](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_TLC5940_Arduino_Library) for my early testing with an Arduino Nano but it doesnt support the ESP32 out of the Box.

I know there are configuration files for diffrent micro controllers but i dont know how to change them to work with an ESP32.

Does somebody know how i can modify the library to work with ESP32 or does somebody has an other library that will work with the ESP32?

Comment: There is an esp32 [library](https://github.com/botanicfields/BF-005/blob/master/BF-005v3/BF_ESP32_TLC5940_SEG16.h) that utilises TLC5940, you maybe able to modified it for your application.

Comment: @hcheung Thank you for that hint. I already stumbled across this library but i hoped for an easier "plug and play" solution because my indepth knowledge about this IC and the ESP32 is limited. But i guess i need to invest the time and modify this one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about why don't work with esp32, it's wired.
in any case the library from tensy daddy (Paul Stoffregen) for this IC is marked for
support ESP32.

this is the link:

https://github.com/PaulStoffTlc5940%20by%20Paul%20Stoffregenregen/Tlc5940

if can be usefull i've tried also the TLC5947 with adafruit library,
the IC has very similar characteristics and works well with ESP32.

link:

https://learn.adafruit.com/tlc5947-tlc59711-pwm-led-driver-breakout/downloads-and-links